# How to make a button to disable elements in a class

Tags: html, css, wordpress, button, divi

I am trying to create a filtering system for a portfolio site in wordpress (using the Divi Builder) and would love to be able to make a button/buttons to set elements with specific classes on a page to `display: none` when the button is clicked on.
If anyone has ideas on how this can be done that would be super appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you unable to use Javascript to achieve this? I believe that a JS Function can do this fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery, the .show() and .hide() Functions work on jQuery objects.
For example `$('.dataholder').hide().filter( (index,element) => $("body").innerHTML == "abc" ).show()` will hide all nodes with class dataholder and then show those containing abc.

Otherwise you have to use something like

```
element = document.querySelector('#dataholder')
element.style.display = 'none'
```

Or

```
elements = document.querySelectorAll('.dataholder')
elements.forEach( element => element.style.display = 'none' )
```

Comment: Thanks for the support, I've tried to follow along your suggestions and a few tutorials. I've done this but not sure why it isn't working. Any thoughts on what I did wrong? 


`<script>

function uxFunction() {

  document.querySelectorAll("#dreamseeds, #angelaart, #sdc, #ytv, #intime, #wherenext").style.display = "block";

  document.querySelectorAll("#airdesk, #prints, #notebook, #markets, #corporart, #recipe").style.display = "none";

}

</script>`

Comment: You have to use querySelector or forEach. querySelectorAll yields multiple objects, js doesn't support setting individual properties of the contained objects like that. `document.querySelectorAll("#dreamseeds, #angelaart, #sdc, #ytv, #intime, #wherenext").forEach( element => element.style.display = "block" );`

Comment: I would really recommend you to get jquery, if you at all can. It will make some things like this a lot easier for beginners.